# Php array looping, creating dynamic variable for purchasing form

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, purchase-order

Still getting used to stackoverflow excuse my rookie-ness.. :)

Have an SQL query that returns a data put into a table in php. I want this table to be used for purchasing.

My idea was to use the product id, meaning i would use a dynamic php variable (not sure if I'm doing that right now) believe I saw a post something like $.$varaible$.$ it wasn't very clear and was a different subject.

My code is as follows:

```html
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Type = 'Game'");
?>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="headGame">Buy Some Games Man</h1>
</div>
<br />
<div class="wrapper">

<?php
    echo 
    "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Picture </th>
    <th> Console </th>
    <th> Description </th>
    <th> Price </th>
    <th> Amount </th>
    </tr>";

    echo '<form id="gamesOrder" action="purchase.php">';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['Pd_Key'];
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . '<img class="prdPic" src="'. $row['Picture']. '">' . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['Type2'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['Price'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>"  . '<input type="number" min="0" max="100"; name="'.$id.'" value=0>' . "</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="  BUY  ">';
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

When I click the submit it changes the url but nothing happens, it doesn't redirect.

Any advice on how to get this entire process to work. The variable being used in a purchasing form, via a php file ie (purchase.php) and the variable to use for this.

EDIT - Had minor errors, but still not 100% on variable %id, won't that get redefined each loop, how can I have it dynamic so it can be used in a form to identify what the user wants to buy.

Now redirects but not to purchase.php

URL is `~/purchase.php?1=0&2=0&3=0&4=0&5=0&6=0&7=0&8=0&9=0&10=0&11=0&12=0&13=0&14=0&15=0&16=0&17=0&18=0&19=0&20=0&21=0`

Thanks you legends you!! =D

Comment: did you try the following changes? didn't it work?

Comment: Yes so the link works now. Thanks all. Going to quickly see if the $id is working via Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing form caret:

```
echo '<form id="gamesOrder" action"purchase.php"';
```

should be:

```
echo '<form id="gamesOrder" action="purchase.php">';
```

Also you concatenation for ID is incorrect:

```
echo"<td>"  . '<input type="number" min="0" max="100"; name=".$id." value=0>' . "</td>";
```

should just be:

```
echo"<td>"  . '<input type="number" min="0" max="100"; name="id" value="' .$id. '" value=0></td>';
```

To access the id in purchase.php use the following code:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
```

And you need to assign the action to the form with an equals sign:

```
action="myaction.php"
```

Comment: not just that. missing `=` on action, invalid `.$id.` concatenation inside the table body, blah blah blah. the code's full of typos/mistakes.

Comment: Wow, sorry little sleep deprived atm... I'll check that quickly.

Comment: your top and bottom line for the form tag is the same, you didn't add the equal sign ;)

Comment: So edited those changes, still doesn't seem to redirect. Also is that variable going to be usable in a form for purchasing?

Comment: Not sure what happened first time I tried, but linking now. Any advice on how to use the variable to complete the purchase would be great.

Comment: I have updated my answer. 1) you need to give a standard name to the $id input. 2) you access the id with `$_GET['id']` in purchase.php

Answer (score 0):

And you don't pass the id right...

```
    echo"<td>"  . '<input type="number" min="0" max="100"; name=".$id." value=0>' . "</td>";
```

should be

```
    echo"<td>"  . '<input type="number" min="0" max="100"; name="'.$id.'" value=0>' . "</td>";
```

Ough, and on form you need to put action =

```
    echo '<form id="gamesOrder" action="purchase.php">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you've got some HTML error, lets see:

- In the Form element you need to close it and also include the method (as POST), see:

  < form id="gamesOrder" action="purchase.php" method="POST">
- To send data using a form you will need to include the data from the data base in form fields like this:

  echo '< input type="text" name="myFieldName" value="'.$row['Price'].'">';

Any question let me know...
Cheers.

Comment: Cheers mate. Re- method.

I was going to just requery the database using the product key to acquire all other data, is this not a suitable method? RE-Price

Comment: You are welcome! So about requery, depends on how you wanna your project to be, I mean, if you first query all the data (name, price, id, description, quantity, etc.) so all you need is to pass this fields (you can use type='hidden' for some of they) or just send one field ID and requery, but it's gonna slow down your system requesting 2 queries to do the job that could be done by one. You can take a look in w3schools.com as well to know more about forms with PHP. best part... it's for free...  lol. Good luck and let me know in case of questions.

Comment: Heya Rafael, How would you go about processing the order then.

Little stuck (completely brain dead due to lack of sleep - not that I can afford to atm, deadlines) on how.

Thinking something like:
IE if($id > 0)$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Pd_Key = $id).